# Google Charts are not displaying in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-visualization

i am using Firefox browser and i used Google Charts for my website. Every thing is running correctly, all graphs are running. when i reopen the browser at night it is not showing any graph. i don't know what happened because no errors were found just blank page is displaying. If any one knows what is the problem behind this please tell me. i have checked in IE but it is not working in IE too.

Comment: The Visualization API had a massive update yesterday that removed a lot of deprecated features.  Check the error console in Firefox to see what shows up there.

Comment: yes you are right there are too many errors e.g: [01:33:59.900] SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead @ http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js:1

Comment: If you have jQuery problems, they are not related to the Visualization API (as there is no cross-contamination between the two API's).

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday(Nov 26th 2013) there was an update released to [google's visualization tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes). I would suggest joining the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-visualization-api). I also answered a question which had some common issues I my self faced after the update, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20234491/1445460).

I'd suggest posting some code as it could greatly help in determining the issue. But code aside I'll take a wild guess and assume you are using one or more of the following [formatters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters):

```
TableArrowFormat
TableBarFormat
TableColorFormat
TableDateFormat
TableNumberFormat
TablePatternFormat
```

If you are, just remove the word `Table` from the front of it and that should do the trick. The functions were renamed.

Comment: No actually i have a problem with data types in getting the array from mysql to JsonTable.  I have used Time as string and speed as float but now float data type is no longer available. if i replaced the speed as string then it will show the error that sting will not be used on X-axis.

Comment: i have posted my code on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268011/google-charts-are-not-displaying-with-new-release